# Formula to compare values on two tabs

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I need to combine data from two sheets into a single sheet. We're mapping new employee import data to historical ID's. This will allow us to map historical sales imports to the current employees.

I have a workbook with two sheets. I want to create a VLOOKUP that will search the First_Name and Last_Name columns C and D in sheet 1 and compare the normalized First_Name and Last_Name columns E and G in the second sheet. The result of the lookup entering the value of the Employee_ID into column A on the first sheet.

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Sweeney

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use VLOOKUP with 2 cells (First_Name and Last_Name), you need to concatenate the 2 cells to column used for VLOOKUP. After concatenation, you can use the concatenated cell in VLOOKUP.

[image]